# crontab: login name too long

Tags: solaris, cron, user-accounts

When I try to edit do crontab for a user with a long username on solaris 10 I get this error:

crontab: login name too long

Is this a known problem and is there a solution for it (without changing the username)?

The username is 27 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

I never saw that before.

But, while we don't discover how to fix this issue, try to edit the crontab file by vi command.

```
vi /var/spool/cron/crontabs/"username"
```

It will help you meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

After some quick googling it appears that many of Sun's unix tools follow the Unix convention of 8 or less character usernames. It seems that Solaris will allow you to use longer usernames, but it is not a certified or supported configuration.

Comment: True enough. But not really helpful, is it?